# Managing large data files, vector and raster, in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, data-management

I work for a local authority so use data covering a large area. Therefore some datasets I use become large and cumbersome.

For example I have a vector layer for contours and a raster layer for hillshade. As I am relatively inexperienced I created Booth of these of a series of tiled points and created a single file. I am happy with the results but performance is slower.

What are the main options available to improve the performance of the vector layers for a single user on one PC and for a team?  This should allow me to both display and analyse the data efficiently.

What are the main options available to improve the performance of the raster layer?

Comment: Do you have access to a server, so you could host your own WMS? Could you reduce the resolution of the DEM/countour layer? What do you mean by "I created both of these of a series of tiled points and created a single file"? Aren't they two files? Why do you actually need hillshade? Would it be feasible to turn on these layers only when you really need them?

Comment: To improve performance of a raster layer in qgis, convert it to a single GeoTiff and add external overviews (fastest) or a virtual raster with external overviews (generally fast).  You can create a virtual raster then save it as a GeoTiff.  Overviews are created in the properties view (right click the layer).

Comment: You could try creating a geopackage.  This uses a sqlite database and can include optimisations for both vector (spatial index) and raster (overviews and internal tiles).

Comment: In addition to the suggestions to build a spatial index for vectors and pyramids for rasters , you might check out Settings - Options - Rendering for some settings that affect rendering speed. You can generalize/simplify vectors like contours (those from LiDAR are often quite noisy) as well.  If you have rasters with complex symbology, especially 32 bit floating point, converting them to rendered 8 bit can greatly improve speed.  If you have complex labeling expressions, masking or locations, or complex symbology expressions or symbols, those can slow drawing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your contours, you can

- use simple [scale dependent visibility](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=scale%20dependent#scale-dependent-visibility) to turn the layer off when zoomed out too far
- build a [spatial index](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html?highlight=spatial%20index#create-spatial-index)
- you could also try a [rule-based symbology](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=rule%20based%20symbology#rule-based-renderer) to limit the contour interval shown as you zoom out
- you may need to build an [attribute index](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html?highlight=attribute%20index#create-attribute-index) on the elevation field to help speed up any labelling and rule-based symbology

For your raster, you can

- build [raster overviews (pyramids)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html?highlight=overviews#id9)

Answer (score 4):

The best way to manage your large datasets is to store them in a spatial database like PostGIS. The loading speed will be twice faster.

Comment: PostGIS will also allow you to do very fast spatial operations.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I don't know much about databases, so will check it out.

Comment: @boberdorf This answer is a bit of an over generalisation. Where I work, our very large datasets are stored in a remote spatial database (which is tuned for speed) and it's still way quicker to pull the data down to a local filesystem format to do anything with it. A local database may be quicker, but will have overhead in setting up and tuning.

Comment: Geoserver is not a spatial database.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out PostGIS

- https://postgis.net/

Also you can access Postgres databases in QGIS

- https://www.bostongis.com/blog/index.php?/archives/271-New-in-QGIS-3.2-Save-Project-to-PostgreSQL.html
- https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/databases/db_browser.html